# Wifi access gateway?

Tags: wifi

I am looking for a open source system which allows to control access of users at the WiFi point, allowing user to login and get access to the internet based on data/time quota.
This should be ready to be extended and support many devices, best bet is being able to work on generic Linux and firmwares based on openwrt or similar.
I don’t think there are an ‘industry standard ‘ of any kind, although this looks like pretty common functionality widely used. So, any recommendations are welcomed